# push notification iOS 8 not Receiveing

Tags: ios, xcode, apple-push-notifications, ios8.3

Push notification in iOS 8 not receiving.

Can any one tell me what could be problem on server side. It shows push notification send successfully but not receive on device.

Please see PHP and Xcode is this right?

```
<?php    
// Put your device token here (without spaces):
$deviceToken = '123213123123312321312312313131231231231232131312';

// Put your private key's passphrase here:
$passphrase = '*********';
$a = 1;
// Put your alert message here:
//$message = $_GET['msg'];
$message = $_POST['msg'];    
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//$myString= $_GET['id'];
$myString= $_POST['id'];

$registrationIds =explode(',', $myString);

foreach ($registrationIds as $deviceid)
  {

$ctx = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'cert.pem');
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);

// Open a connection to the APNS server
$fp = stream_socket_client(
    'ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195', $err,
    $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);

if (!$fp)
    exit("Failed to connect: $err $errstr" . PHP_EOL);

echo 'Connected to APNS' . PHP_EOL;

// Create the payload body
$body['aps'] = array(
    'alert' => $message,
    'badge' => $a,
    'sound' => 'default'
    );

// Encode the payload as JSON
$payload = json_encode($body);

// Build the binary notification
$msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $deviceid) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;

// Send it to the server
$result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));

echo $result ;

if (!$result)
    echo 'Message not delivered' . PHP_EOL;
else
    echo 'Message successfully delivered' . PHP_EOL;

// Close the connection to the server
fclose($fp);
}
?>
```

On AppDelegate xcode

```
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0)
    {
        UIUserNotificationSettings *settings =
        [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:UIUserNotificationTypeAlert |
         UIUserNotificationTypeBadge |
         UIUserNotificationTypeSound
                                          categories:nil];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
    }
    else
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
         UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert |
         UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge |
         UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound];
    }
```

Comment: Are you sending your device token to server?

Answer (score 0):

You are using the production APNS server:

```
ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195
```

In order for your app to receive push notifications, you have to build and sign it with a production certificate. You can do that by generating an Ad Hoc build.

If you want to send push to your device running the application in Development mode, you have to push the notifications to the sandbox APNS server:

```
ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195
```

More details in the Apple docs: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/CommunicatingWIthAPS.html